# how to make sure that an array of bytes is encoded by Base64?

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays, base64, decoding

I have a method as below:

```
public void AddAttachment(byte[] attachment)
{
// how to make sure that the attachemnt is encoded by Base64?
}
```

how to make sure the AddAttachment method accepts an array of bytes that is encoded with Base64?

For example the below is a valid input before being sent to this method:

```
string attachmentInString = "Hello test";
byte[] attachmentInBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(attachmentInString);
```

but if the attachmentInBytes was encoded using ASCII or etc, the AddAttachement method should throw an exception.

How to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: The question is very unclear. Why the use of `DecodeFrom64` if you want to _encode_ something? Please clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the title in the question is very clear if you read it. how to make sure the AddAttachment method accepts an array of bytes that is encoded with Base64? I updated the body as well.

Comment: Repeating the question does not make it any clearer. What are you trying to achieve here? Exactly?

Comment: @Oded He wants to check if attachment is encoded in base64.

Comment: Your example makes no sense at all. The output of `FromBase64String` can be any possible `byte[]` since you this is the decode operation, not the encode operation. Also since `"Hello test"` is no valid base64 string, it will fail anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is a way to represent a stream of bytes as a string. If you want the attachment to be a base64 string then change the signature to  `public void AddAttachment(string attachment)`

Then decode the Base64 using `byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment)`

If you want to encode the attachment into base64:

```
public void AddAttachment(byte[] attachment) {
   string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(attachment)
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks but "string attchment" is not relevant. I'd need a validation inside the AddAttachment method to make sure it receives the correctly encoded array of bytes. is it clear?

Comment: Do you mean the byte[] is actually a base64 string?

Comment: for example this is the valid encoded bytes before being sent to this method: byte[] attachmentInBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(attachmentInString);

Answer (score 0):

From your question I find you are misunderstanding something, hope this helps.
[Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) accepts a string(which is always like `ALJWKA==`) and outputs a `byte[]`, while [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.TObase64string.aspx) is opposite. So your code:

```
string attachmentInString = "Hello test";
byte[] attachmentInBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(attachmentInString);
```

will throw an exception, because "Hello test" is not a valid base64 string. See the other method

```
public void AddAttachment(byte[] attachment)
```

the argument is a `byte[]`, so in this method you at most convert it to a base64 like string. You can't tell if a `byte[]` is a valid base64 string or not. You can only do this to a string:

```
public void AddAttachment(string attachment) //well I know it looks strange
{
   byte[] bytes = null;
   try
   {
       bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment);
   }
   catch
   {
       //invalid string format
   }
}
```